# Saving data from excel to text file in PB8

Tags: excel, powerbuilder, ole-automation

I am using the below code to transfer the data in an excel file to a tab delimited text file in Powerbuilder 8.But it only transfers the data from the sheet 1. I want the data from all the sheets in the excel file to be transferred into a single consolidated text file. Can someone please help?

Code--

```
 integer iresult

 OLEObject MyOleObject
 MyOleObject = CREATE OLEObject
 iResult = MyOleObject.ConnectToObject("D:\AP52_All.xlsx");
  messagebox("result",iresult)
 IF iResult = 0 THEN

       MyOleObject.Application.Workbooks(1).SaveAs("D:\AP52_Rates_1.txt",21) 


 End if
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the worksheets within the workbook doing something similar to this VBA code:

`//refer total number of worksheets in the specified workbook using the Worksheets.Count property:
For i = 1 To MyOleObject.Application.Worksheets.Count
   MsgBox MyOleObject.Application.Worksheets(i).Name
Next i`

Answer (score 0):

Following Matt's suggestion, instead of the line

```
MyOleObject.Application.Workbooks(1).SaveAs("D:\AP52_Rates_1.txt",21)
```

you can use:

```
book = MyOleObject.Application.Workbooks(1)
For i = 1 To MyOleObject.Application.Worksheets.Count
    book.Worksheet(i).SaveAs("D:\AP52_Rates_"& i & ".txt",21)
Next
```

and later, combine all the text files.